# Why is my program saying that the integer number is too large for Project Euler #3 (Java)?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean isPrime(long num)
    {
        for(long i=2; i<=num/2; i++)
        {
            if(num%i==0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static long findLargestPrimeFactor(long n)
    {
        long max=0;
        for(long factor=2; factor<n; factor++)
        {
            if(n % factor==0)
            {
                if(isPrime(n/factor)==true)
                {
                    max=factor;
                }
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

However, when I run it, it says that the integer 600851475143 is too large. can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't see any reference to that number in your code. Are you getting  a runtime exception? What is "it" that gives you this message?

Comment: Change all `long`s to `double`s

Comment: How are you calling your `findLargestPrimeFactor` method and where are you seeing this error?

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to wager you're calling

```
 isLargestPrimeFactor(600851475143);
```

since that's the problem given in Project Euler #3.   This will fail to compile with an error:

```
  error: integer number too large: 600851475143
```

Correct? If that's the case, try:

```
 isLargestPrimeFactor(600851475143L);
```

The "L" suffix tells the compiler that you mean it to be a long literal, not an int (otherwise the compiler will treat it as an integer literal, and it's too large to fit in an int)